# how can i get data from sharepoint userprofiles in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get the data of UserProfiles from SharePoint 2010 site using Objective-C within xCode.Now I am using the SOAP service in my project. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction here?  Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean "iOS" or "Cocoa" instead of *Xcode*.

If possible, avoid SOAP. It's much easier to access a web service via REST and using JSON as transport format - and in 99.8% of all use cases, a RESTful web service and JSON will fulfill all your requirements up to 100%.

What you need to accomplish your task can be summarized into "networking development", which involves `NSURLConnection` (and related friend classes), and  `NSJSONSerialization` and a few other system classes depending on your needs.

Unless you stay with a RESTful web service and JSON and moderate requirements, networking may become quickly complex. And it becomes unnecessarily complex when using SOAP. Possibly you may want to utilize a third party library which may help here.

I'm assuming you are already familiar with the basic major principles when programming in Objective-C and for Mac OS X and iOS. So, I would suggest to start with reading examples from the Apple docs involving networking and utilizing `NSURLConnection` (e.g. MVCNetworking).